# How can stage variable be added in Integration Path override api gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to use s3 with api gateway. I have a stage variable that stored bucket name for each stage. But not able to use it in path override or path parameters
[image]

instead of bucket/{key} want to use stageVariable.variable/{key}.
I have tried using ${stageVariable.variable}/{key},'${stageVariable.variable}'/{key}
Nothing is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a sage variable named `bucketname`:

[image]

You can reference this variable in the integration request as follows:

[image]

Please note, we reference a stage variable as `${stageVariables.name}`, where the name is my case was `bucketname`. You can also find some examples in the AWS documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/stage-variables.html